# How can I perform WinForm cross threading operations without a reference to the affected control?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I just implemented a few generic binding collections, which will soon be used as datasources for controls of a winform application.

My problem is that those collections may not be accessed by the same thread as the one of the control they are bounded to and this would lead to cross-thread exceptions or maybe other issues.
I am trying to marshal this thread crossing operations, considering that I would rather not have any reference to the control outside the UI thread, so I will not use neither the `Control.Invoke` method nor the `BeginInvoke` one.

After deeper investigation, I have the feeling that my problem could be solved by accessing either a  UI thread dispatcher or synchronization context, and use them inside of my `OnListChanged` function of the binding collection.

like this I could make a call to their Invoke or Send methods if necessary.

If I was using WPF I think it should be possible to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to get the application dispatcher at any time. 
Is there a look alike solution I could use with my WinForm application? Or something else that could allow me to check within which thread the list modification is performed and marshal the cross-threading operations if needed

I just found this piece of code that could be interesting for me, unfortunately in my case the handler target is not a dispatcherobject but a currency manager. Is there a way to have the same behaviour then ?

```
  protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
var notifyCollectionChangedEventHandler = CollectionChanged;

if (notifyCollectionChangedEventHandler == null)
    return;

foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in notifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.GetInvocationList())
    {
    var dispatcherObject = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;

    if (dispatcherObject != null && !dispatcherObject.CheckAccess())
        {
        dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, args);
        }
    else
        handler(this, args); // note : this does not execute handler in target thread's context
    }
}
```

Comment: Your snippet does not demonstrate the problem.  There is one Red Flag,  the appearance of Dispatcher in this code.  That doesn't belong in a Winforms app.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Control.Invoke pattern? What is wrong with it? The WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send "pattern" doesn't make your code any prettier ;-)

Comment: Could it be that the Record object is bound to the thread that created it? In this case the Record object is bound to the background thread and you're trying to add it to the DataGridView, which is bound to the main UI thread.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way. Especially keep in mind that it is not useful to state simply that "an exception occurred". You need to provide precise details, including the exact type of exception, the exact message for the exception, and the full stack trace. Please also be sure to provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.